# How to make coverage with internal observable method in testing

Tags: angular, angular-test

here is the component methods:

```
resetPage(): void {
        this.deletedClinicPosProps = { appId: [] };
        this.addedClinicPosProps = { appId: [] };
        this.resetHeaders();
        this.canSaveEnabled = { a: false, b: false, c: false };
        this.profileForm.hfsForm.reset();
        this.isDataSaved = false;
        this.setPage();
    }
```

and another method which calls the above method on post:

```
postClinicUpdate() {
        this.postProfile();
        if (!this.profileForm.isHfsFormIsValid) {
            return;
        }
        const {
            slide,
            timezone: { codeId },
        } = this.profileFormValue;
        const { sjmAccDTO } = this.userProfile;
        const sjmAccountId = sjmAccDTO.sjmAccountId;

        const postData: UpdateClinicProps = {
            sjmAccountId: sjmAccountId,
            hfsStatus: slide === true ? 1 : 0,
            timeZoneCd: codeId,
            addedClinicIds: this.addedClinicPosProps.appId,
            deletedClinicIds: this.deletedClinicPosProps.appId,
            deletedCountryCds:
                this.profileForm.countrySelectionProps.removedCountries,
            addedCountryCds:
                this.profileForm.countrySelectionProps.addedCountries,
        };
        this.personnelViewDataService
            .updateClinics(postData)
            .subscribe((updates) => {
                if (updates) {
                    this.resetPage();
                    this.actOfSaveEnabled = false;
                    this._location.back();
                }
            });
    }
```

mock service for testing:

```
const mockPersonnelViewDataService = {
        userProfileWithCodes$: of(testMockData),
        fetchUserProfileWithCode: function () {
            return this.userProfileWithCodes$;
        },
        updateClinics: function () {
            return { subscribe: () => {} };
        },
        responseUpdateClinic$: of({}),
    };
```

testing:

```
it('should call postClinicUpdate to save data, and rest the page', fakeAsync(() => {
        const updateClinics = spyOn(service, 'updateClinics').and.callThrough();
        const postClinicUpdate = spyOn(
            component,
            'postClinicUpdate'
        ).and.callThrough();
        const resetPage = spyOn(component, 'resetPage').and.callThrough();
        const btnRemoveClinic = fixture.debugElement.query(
            By.css('#btn-removeClinic')
        ).nativeElement;
        const btnPostClinic = fixture.debugElement.query(
            By.css('#btn-postClinic')
        ).nativeElement;
        profileTable = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('table#details-view'));
        const checkBox: HTMLInputElement = profileTable.query(
            By.css('tbody input[type=checkbox]')
        ).nativeElement;

        checkBox.click();
        tick(1000);

        btnRemoveClinic.click();
        tick(1000);
        btnPostClinic.click();
        expect(postClinicUpdate).toHaveBeenCalled();
        tick(1000);
        component.resetPage();
        expect(resetPage).toHaveBeenCalled();
    }));
```

no error thrown. all are success. But my `resetPage()` method not under the test coverage. still it show under uncover part. How to make my `resetPage` come under coverage with current testing?

what I missed or what change need i do?
thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You are directly calling `component.resetPage();` that is probably why
  the test case is passing.
- updateClinics returns an object not an observable

Remove `component.resetPage()` and add `return of('test')` to the mock

```js
const mockPersonnelViewDataService = {
  updateClinics: function () {
    return of('test');
  },

 ...
};
```

Comment: getting an error as ` Error: Expected spy resetPage to have been called.` after I am de changes

Comment: try replacing component.resetPage() with  component.postClinicUpdate()

Comment: it's not throws any error. but the reset method not under the coverage

Comment: expect(resetPage).toHaveBeenCalled(); this assertion is passing? but the coverage report does not show that this lines this.resetPage();
                    this.actOfSaveEnabled = false;
                    this._location.back(); are not covered?

Comment: yes you are correct.

Comment: is it possible to share a screenshot of the coverage report?

Comment: sure will try for it .

Comment: Not able to share because of corporate policy.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/250109/discussion-between-3gwebtrain-and-mr-stash).